# JMap dump format specification

Tags: java, heap-dump, jmap

Are there any open specifications for jmap heap dump format?

Thanks for help!

Comment: do you need to read the binary data ?

Comment: @Santosh, I need to build a histogram of Class instances amount form heap dump. So, yes, I need to read binary data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need an histogram of the heap, you can use `jmap -histo <pid>` to get the histogram from your live JVM. If you already have the heap dump file, with [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) (Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool) you can load the dump and easily get the histogram you are looking for.

Maybe [Lars Vogel tiny tutorial on it](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseMemoryAnalyser/article.html) can be an easy first step.

Regarding the *hprof binary format*, I bookmarked this some time ago: http://java.net/downloads/heap-snapshot/hprof-binary-format.html, but developing your own parser to get an histogram is totaly overkill.

Comment: Yes, I know this. Thanks for the answer. As I specified above, I need heap dump to be parsed by my program (module). To do that I need some docs. I googled for them, but didn't find any useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Other simpler solution for histogram is to use [jhat](http://ranjanrakesh.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/java-memory-analysis-just-using-jdk/) without being worried about the format. you can drill down and do various things.